# What may be wrong about my use of SetGraphicsRootDescriptorTable in D3D12?

Tags: direct3d

For 7 meshes that I would like to draw, I load 7 textures and create the corresponding SRVs in a descriptor heap. Then there's another SRV for IMGUI. There are also 3 CBVs, for triple buffer usage. So it should be like: `| srv x7 | srv x1 | cbv x3|` in the heap.

The problem I met is that when I called `SetGraphicsRootDescriptorTable` on range 0, which should be an SRV (which is the texture actually), something went wrong. Here's the code:

```
 ID3D12DescriptorHeap* ppHeaps[] = { pCbvSrvDescriptorHeap, pSamplerDescriptorHeap };
    pCommandList->SetDescriptorHeaps(_countof(ppHeaps), ppHeaps);
    pCommandList->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST);
    pCommandList->IASetIndexBuffer(pIndexBufferViewDesc);
    pCommandList->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, pVertexBufferViewDesc);
    CD3DX12_GPU_DESCRIPTOR_HANDLE srvHandle(pCbvSrvDescriptorHeap->GetGPUDescriptorHandleForHeapStart(), indexMesh, cbvSrvDescriptorSize);
    pCommandList->SetGraphicsRootDescriptorTable(0, srvHandle);
    pCommandList->SetGraphicsRootDescriptorTable(1, pSamplerDescriptorHeap->GetGPUDescriptorHandleForHeapStart());
```

If `indexMesh` is 5, SetGraphicsRootDescriptorTable will cause the following error though the render output seems still good. And when `indexMesh` is 6, the following error will still occur and there will be another identical error except that the offset 8 turns into 9.

`D3D12 ERROR: CGraphicsCommandList::SetGraphicsRootDescriptorTable: Specified GPU Descriptor Handle (ptr = 0x400750000002c0 at 8 offsetInDescriptorsFromDescriptorHeapStart) of type CBV, for Root Signature (0x0000020A516E8BF0:'m_rootSignature')'s Descriptor Table (at Parameter Index [0])'s Descriptor Range (at Range Index [0] of type D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_RANGE_TYPE_SRV) have mismatching types. All descriptors of descriptor ranges declared STATIC (not-DESCRIPTORS_VOLATILE) in a root signature must be initialized prior to being set on the command list. [ EXECUTION ERROR #646: INVALID_DESCRIPTOR_HANDLE]`

That is really weird, because I suppose that the only thing that may cause this is that `cbvSrvDescriptorSize` is not right. It is 64, and it is set by `m_device->GetDescriptorHandleIncrementSize(D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_HEAP_TYPE_CBV_SRV_UAV);`which I think should work. Besides, if I set it to another value such as 32, the application would crash.

So if `cbvSrvDescriptorSize` is right, why would the correct `indexMesh` cause the wrong offset of the descriptor handle? The consequence of this error is that it seems to be influencing my CBV which breaks the render output. Any suggestion would be appreciated, thanks!

---

Thanks for Chuck's suggestion, here's the code about the rootSig:

```
CD3DX12_DESCRIPTOR_RANGE1 ranges[3];
ranges[0].Init(D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_RANGE_TYPE_SRV, 4, 0, 0, D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_RANGE_FLAG_DATA_STATIC);
ranges[1].Init(D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_RANGE_TYPE_SAMPLER, 1, 0);
ranges[2].Init(D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_RANGE_TYPE_CBV, 1, 0, 0, D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_RANGE_FLAG_DATA_STATIC);

CD3DX12_ROOT_PARAMETER1 rootParameters[3];
rootParameters[0].InitAsDescriptorTable(1, &ranges[0], D3D12_SHADER_VISIBILITY_PIXEL);
rootParameters[1].InitAsDescriptorTable(1, &ranges[1], D3D12_SHADER_VISIBILITY_PIXEL);
rootParameters[2].InitAsDescriptorTable(1, &ranges[2], D3D12_SHADER_VISIBILITY_ALL);

CD3DX12_VERSIONED_ROOT_SIGNATURE_DESC rootSignatureDesc;
rootSignatureDesc.Init_1_1(_countof(rootParameters), rootParameters, 0, nullptr, D3D12_ROOT_SIGNATURE_FLAG_ALLOW_INPUT_ASSEMBLER_INPUT_LAYOUT);

ComPtr<ID3DBlob> signature;
ComPtr<ID3DBlob> error;
        
ThrowIfFailed(D3DX12SerializeVersionedRootSignature(&rootSignatureDesc, featureData.HighestVersion, &signature, &error));
ThrowIfFailed(m_device->CreateRootSignature(0, signature->GetBufferPointer(), signature->GetBufferSize(), IID_PPV_ARGS(&m_rootSignature)));
NAME_D3D12_OBJECT(m_rootSignature);
```

And here's some declarations in the pixel shader:

```
Texture2DArray       g_textures : register(t0);
SamplerState    g_sampler : register(s0);
cbuffer cb0 : register(b0)
{
    float4x4 g_mWorldViewProj;
    float3 g_lightPos;
    float3 g_eyePos;
    ...
};
```

Comment: Where is your C++ code or HLSL syntax that declares your rootsig?

Comment: Thanks you @ChuckWalbourn , I've edited the question.

Comment: Try ``D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_RANGE_OFFSET_APPEND`` instead of ``D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_RANGE_FLAG_DATA_STATIC``--or just don't specify that 4th parameter.

Comment: Thank you again Chuck, but it seems that the problem is still there.

Answer (score 2):

It's not very often I come across the exact problem I'm experiencing (my code is almost verbatim) and it's an in-progress post! Let's suffer together.

My problem turned out to be the calls to CreateConstantBufferView()/CreateShaderResourceView() - I was passing srvHeap->GetCPUDescriptorHandleForHeapStart() as the destDescriptor handle. These need to be offset to match your table layout (the offsetInDescriptorsFromTableStart param of CD3DX12_DESCRIPTOR_RANGE1).

I found it easier to just maintain one D3D12_CPU_DESCRIPTOR_HANDLE to the heap and just increment handle.ptr after every call to CreateSomethingView() which uses that heap.

```
CD3DX12_DESCRIPTOR_RANGE1 rangesV[1] = {{}};
CD3DX12_DESCRIPTOR_RANGE1 rangesP[1] = {{}};

// Vertex
rangesV[0].Init(D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_RANGE_TYPE_CBV, 1, 0, 0, D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_RANGE_FLAG_NONE, 0);     // b0 at desc offset 0

// Pixel
rangesP[0].Init(D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_RANGE_TYPE_SRV, 1, 0, 0, D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_RANGE_FLAG_NONE, 1);     // t0 at desc offset 1

CD3DX12_ROOT_PARAMETER1 rootParameters[2] = {{}};
rootParameters[0].InitAsDescriptorTable(1, &rangesV[0], D3D12_SHADER_VISIBILITY_VERTEX);
rootParameters[1].InitAsDescriptorTable(1, &rangesP[0], D3D12_SHADER_VISIBILITY_PIXEL);

D3D12_CPU_DESCRIPTOR_HANDLE srvHeapHandle = srvHeap->GetCPUDescriptorHandleForHeapStart();

// ----

device->CreateConstantBufferView(&cbvDesc, srvHeapHandle);
srvHeapHandle.ptr += device->GetDescriptorHandleIncrementSize(D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_HEAP_TYPE_CBV_SRV_UAV);

// ----

device->CreateShaderResourceView(texture, &srvDesc, srvHeapHandle);
srvHeapHandle.ptr += device->GetDescriptorHandleIncrementSize(D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_HEAP_TYPE_CBV_SRV_UAV);
```

Perhaps an enum would help keep it tidier and more maintainable, though. I'm still experimenting.

Comment: You may want to look at ``DescriptorHeap`` / ``DescriptorPile`` in the [DirectX Tool Kit for DX12](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK12/wiki).